# What is the difference between forceid and entry_id on a template?

Tags: entryid

I will delete this question if forceid is singular to the site I am dealing with but what is the difference between forceid and entry_id if they both equal the same thing? I am also dealing with the Page module if that helps.

```
{embed="site/_head" forceid="18" weblogname="main"}  
    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="site" show_pages="yes" rdf="off" disable="trackbacks" limit="1" entry_id="18"}  
{embed="site/_foot" forceid = "18"}
```

Comment: No need to delete the question, it's a good explanation of embed variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, forceid is specific to your site.

In the context of the {embed} tag, forceid is a user created variable--the same kind of thing as weblogname, in your example:

```
{embed="site/_head" forceid="18" weblogname="main"}
```

These become variables available in the embedded templates. E.g., in site/_head, one can use {embed:forceid} and {embed:weblogname} variables whose values are set in the above {embed} tag.